# How to formulate total number of equilateral triangles which can be formed by joining the vertices of a N-sided regular polygon?

Tags: geometry, polygons

I came across a probability question which asks that when a triangle is formed by joining any 3 random vertices of a hexagon, what is the probability that the triangle will be an equilateral one. The correct answer to this problem in solution book is $$\frac{2}{^6C_3}$$
I was wondering if there is a proper method to formulate the total number of equilateral triangles which can be formed by joining the vertices of a polygon with **N** sides. I asked the same question in a discord group and someone gave me this relation without a proof $$\text{the number of equilateral triangles by joining vertices * 3 = the number of sides in polygon}$$

If this relation is true (it works for the above probability question), is there any way we can prove it?

Comment: You should probably take a look at how to ask a [good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). In particular, here some context (why are you interested in this?), some comments (where have you found this relation?), some efforts (what have you tried, what do you think?) would help.

Comment: @AnilCh Thanks for the suggestion, I have edited the question now.

Comment: It's true (if $N$ is divisible by 3, otherwise there are no equilateral triangles) and really quite obvious. Try drawing the triangles for $N=6,9,12$. Do you notice a pattern in the geometry?

Comment: Now the question is way better, thanks for the edit, upvoted it. As per the previous comment, it's true if the number of sides is multiple by $3$. Consider that vertices of a equilateral triangle in a circle must be in particular places of the circle, if you fix one point, the next one would be an angle of $2\pi/3$ after it. Try to use this to see why the claim is true.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to prove it mentally by drawing triangles of equal sides in a polygons of various sides. @StefanAlbrecht you were right, it was quite trivial once I noticed the pattern.